# Two binding constraints - Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

I'm having some troubles to continue solving my system, I'm used to solve such systems but with "one" binding constraint, if someone could give me some helpful hints so I can solve it I will be grateful.

Here is the problem:

Solve the following LP using the Dantzig-Wolfe method:

[image: LP]

This is what I have done so far:

We may notice that there are 6 constraints, and the 2 first constraints will be binding constraints.

- The matrix form of the problem (P) is:

[image: Matrix form of (P)]

Hence:

[image: Matrix A]

And:

[image: Matrix B]

And:

[image: Matrix C]

It is a two-block structure.

i = 1 Constraints block (3) and (4)

i = 2 Constraints block (5) and (6)

Constraints 1 and 2 are binding constraints.

[image: D1]

[image: D2]

[image: b1]

[image: b2]

[image: c1]

[image: c2]

My question is: What can I do so I could solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE, I think the last constraint should be $2x_3 + x_4 \leq 10$.

Comment: I suggest that you refer to the first two constraints as "connecting" constraints rather than "binding" constraints, to avoid confusion. Constraints are "binding" at a particular solution when the slack or surplus is zero at that solution.

Comment: Or *linking constraints* or *complicating constraints*.

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of images.  Are the variables really $\le 10$ or did you instead mean $\ge 0$?